# Urllib2 grab web-page element then reverse it

Tags: python, urllib2

I need to visit http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/ reverse the string and access the website using this URL: http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/password?code=REVERSEDSTRING

How can i do this using urllib2 and Python?

````
link = "http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/password"
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/password")
contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()

revString = request[::-1]
answer = "http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/password?code=" + revString
response = urllib2.urlopen(answer)
response = response.read()
print(response)```
````

Comment: It seems you're trying to reverse the Request object, not the response data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link = "http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/password"
result = requests.get("http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/password")
contents = result.text

revString = contents[::-1]
answer = f"http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/password?code={revString}" 
response = requests.get(answer)
response = response.text
print(response)
```